# Can't seem to push my a folder within my directory to github

Tags: git, github

I've tried so many different things

[image]

but my client folder never seems to want to push

My attempts:

`git rm -rf --cached client`

`git add client`

I then push and it says everything is up to date.

I've tried

`git add *`

`git commit`

and again everything is up to date when I push.

The client folder is a create-react-app, I assume git will also ignore the `/node_modules` within it, or this causing it issues? aka do I have to setup a different repository for the client?

My gitignore file:

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved (ironically after I post the question):

Because the client is another `create-react-app` with a `node_modules` folder I never noticed it hanging when I tried to `git add client`. The solution was simple, edit the `.gitignore` file and add `/client/node_modules` and re-adding the folder. After that, the push went successfully.